# Simple WebRequest via Javascript or JQuery, Is it possible without CORS caveats?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, cors

I've searched and seen variations of this question but some of them have no solid answers while others; no apparent answer.

My question is really very simple but I'll start with describing the issue.

I have a simple httpRequest that I've successfully made within server code (C#) which looks similar to this:

```
var _uri = "https://www.somedomain.com/api";
var _apiKey = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
string credentials = String.Empty;
var responseText = String.Empty;
var someVal = "testvalue";
var postData = "key=" + someVal;

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_apiKey));
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
httpWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var streamWriter = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    streamWriter.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.Write(responseText);
```

I then intiate the call to this code via an asp.net button control and voila! Lifes good and I get my successful response; although even if it were an unsuccessful response, I'd still be ok with it knowing that I did get a response.

So now I want to translate this code to its equivalent in JavaScript or JQuery; either will work for me. So I create the following Client-Side code:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = 'https://www.somedomain.com/api';
    var someVal = "testvalue";
    var _apiKey = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ';
    var postData = "key=" + someVal;

    function getCredentials() {
        var hash = window.btoa(_apiKey);
        return hash;
    }
    function initiateRequest() {
        var creds = getCredentials();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + creds);
        xhr.send(postData);


        xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
        function processRequest(evt) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I then intiate the call to this code via an input type of button and I'm dead in the water! Lifes a b***ch and I get an empty response, a status code of 0 and pretty much nothing of any value to me. I'd be somewhat happier to receive an actual response telling me to go dive off a cliff because it ain't happening due to blah blah blah; or something anyway. Well, that may be a bit exaggerated but you get my point.

So my first inclination is maybe this is a CORS related problem; but since the site I'm accessing serves up API access to the public and all that is required is to authenticate using a provided API Key, I'd presume that CORS has already been compensated for on the server side where the request is being made.

Secondly, because the request was successful from my server side implementation of the code; I would have expected that the client side code should work as well, No???

What critical piece am I missing here? Is my JavaScript code lacking a component that I'm simply overlooking or are there other aspects of what I am attempting that aren't being taken into consideration???

Comment: If its a CORS issue you will see corresponding errors in the browsers Console, is this the case? If so what messages?

Comment: The C# code is unrestricted in what it can do but the JavaScript code runs within a *browser* and is subject to all the security policies/same origin policy implemented there to keep us safe.

Comment: Console reports: https://www.somedomain.com/api required Cross Origin Resource Sharing. https://www.somedomain.com/api required CORS preflight. Origin: http://localhost not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: So it appears that it is in fact a CORS issue after all. But how can I get around it? I understand the preflight in this case was initiated due to the type of request but I don't understand why a public facing API site would restrict any domain at all. Should it be an * on their side?

Comment: Then the site is not available via Ajax, look at its documentation to see if they allow JSONP. Failing that use your C# code as a proxy intermediary.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, very good insight and information. I should have thought to view the console output to acquire a clue to the problem but didn't consider it at the time. I'll explore the JSONP option to determine its viability.